# How to access SharePoint 2013 QR Server Page

Tags: fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

Does anyone know how to get to the QR Server webpage in SharePoint 2013 or is this option even available.

I found this [link](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2011/07/working-with-qr-server-in-fs4sp.html) for SharePoint 2010 with FAST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QR server page has been discontinued in SharePoint 2013.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx#section4

> Search Query web service Description: The Search Query web service is
>   deprecated in SharePoint 2013.
>
> In SharePoint Server 2010, the Search Query web service exposes the
>   SharePoint Enterprise Search capabilities to client applications. This
>   enables you to access search results from client and web applications
>   outside the context of a SharePoint site.
>
> Reason for change: The Search Query web service is deprecated because
>   the client object model (CSOM) and a new REST-based web service are
>   available for developing Office-wide extensibility scenarios. The CSOM
>   exposes the same functionality as the Search Query web service, and a
>   larger set of functionality for stand-alone client applications.
>
> Migration path: Change custom search solutions to use the CSOM or
>   REST-based web service instead of using the Search Query web service.

**This tool might be helpful too:**

http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com

Comment: This tool is defenitely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore how rank is evaluated for a query check out http://powersearching.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/explain-rank-in-sharepoint-2013-search/ which explains how to access the ExplainRank.aspx page located in the 15 hive.